# How can i get particular string from another string using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My sample code :

```
let str = 'myname:is:gopal@gmail.com';
console.log(str.match(":" + "(.*)" + "@")[1]));

returns for above regex => is:gopal // returned value

expected output is => gopal // i want only *gopal*
```

Note: all the strings are dynamic, except `:` and `@` these special characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'myname:is:gopal@gmail.com'.match(/:([^:]+)@/)[1]`

Comment: Please explain exactly which part you're trying to grab; the last "word" before the `@`?

Comment: I am getting `gopal` [`.*:(.*)@.*`](https://regex101.com/r/II6GLn/2)

Comment: Thanks @Mandy8055. i trying to grab **gopal** from my string, this regex ```.*:(.*)@.*```  works fine for string. Many thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help...Cheers =)

Answer (score 0):

Positive Lookahead and Positive Lookbehind can solve your problem.

**UPD**: match non-word characters (by @toto)

```js
s = 'myname:is:gopal@gmail.com'
s.match(/(?<=:)[^:]+(?=@)/)
// --> ["gopal", index: 10, input: "myname:is:gopal@gmail.com", groups: undefined]
```

regex101 test [here](https://regex101.com/r/QkV10m/3)

Comment: What about names that contain non word characters?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks @Mandy8055

```
let str = "myname:is:gopal@gmail.com";
console.log(str.match('.*:(.*)@.*')[1]); // returns gopal
```